# Passing command line arguments through the Remote API

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am using the remote API to create and start containers, but I am not sure how to pass in the command line arguments I normally would when creating from the local machine. Specifically, I am using [this image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/itzg/minecraft-server/), which requires a bunch of arguments I would normally do when running 'docker run [arguments][image]'.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For argument passing, you can like this

```
curl -X POST localhost:2375/containers/create -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"Cmd":["ping", "8.8.8.8"], "Image": "ubuntu"}'
```

Also see: http://blog.flux7.com/blogs/docker/docker-tutorial-series-part-8-docker-remote-api

Comment: Could you summarise the content of the link, in case it breaks?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on which arguments you want to set. Up to port bindings,[here](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.13/#start-a-container) you can find how to do that. In general, you have to use the JSON objects passed as body in your create and in your start request.